# 294GB tar file, what are foreseeable problems?

Tags: tar, cifs, gzip

In rhel 7.8 I have a folder called `/study` that has a bunch of data.  It was ~500GB in size.

I did `gzip -9r /study` and it reduced that folder to 294GB as reported by `du -sh /study`

I then did `tar -cf study.tar /study` and now have a single file named study.tar at 294GB.

I will first copy it to a locally mounted NTFS disk (using ntfs-3g under RHEL 7.8) and then will move that single 294GB tar file to some company provided CIFS share.

Other than time to copy and finding available disk space are there any foreseeable problems I should be aware of, before I do a *rm -r /study* on the original to free up disk?

Comment: I'd copy it back from the network share and run `md5sum` on it as well as the original and ensure the data made it round trip before deleting the source.

Comment: Why convert the individual files to a tarball? Why not just copy the (compressed) files? One less step to worry about and it reduces interdependencies

Comment: @roaima maybe to preserve file permissions? I don't know what ntfs is capable of. On that point how big files can ntfs handle? I remember "once upon a time" when I think fat could not hold *very* big files.

Comment: If you want to retain permissions consider using tar or some other archiver on each file separately

Comment: Am I correct in assuming _you have one tarball containing thousands of *.gz files_?

Comment: yes, the `/stdy` folder contained however many subfolders and millions of files; i did `gzip -r /stdy` such that i do NOT have `study.tar.gz` but it is all the files within that are gzipped.

Comment: did one tarball file because I find much faster easier to copy one item @ 110 MB/s knowing i haven't missed some file within when doing a folder copy to Windows.  Along with preserving all file timestamps and ownership.